# Include whole page in php mail

Tags: php

Is it possible to include a separate html page in a php email?

Example, create a separate page that has all the content on it I want to email it and then include it in a php mail() on another page as the message?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant sending HTML email, yes. You can do that. You just need to add additional headers in the fourth parameter of [mail()](http://www.php.net/mail) and pull the information from the HTML file you have using [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents). Please check this:

http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Comment: However, be aware that most pages will not render the way you expect them to in an email. Inline styles work, but external stylesheets or header style declarations don't. It seems like most clients also ignore any layout commands other than tables. javascript will definitely not run.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible exactly how rationalboss explained. Personally I use [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/) for html emails. It's a pain to get started with if you're not familiar to PEAR, but life has improved once I got it going.

Careful though, html/css does not have the same support in email clients that it does in browsers. You can create a beautiful page and find out that most people receive it with huge glitches due to certain CSS rules being ignored.

Best practice last I heard is to keep it simple and use inline styles for everything. Avoid floats and positioning. In fact, I believe it is actually still safer to use tables when dealing with email layouts if you need things to sit next to each other.

And then test in as many email clients as you can. Then cry and try to fix things.

I hear good things about [Email on Acid](http://www.emailonacid.com/) for testing. It's a pay service but they offer a limited test for 3 clients as well.

If you're just doing a relatively simple email then it shouldn't be too bad. But if you're trying to make something that really looks great I recommend doing some googling on styling html specifically for emails.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll keep it simple with tables I think.  I'm not really bothered about it looking pretty, there are just a lot of mysql queries that were proving a nightmare to run using the standard mail method but work well when run on a separate page and included